# plotting in imshow doesnot take x value correctly

Tags: matplotlib, imshow

I have the following code for 2d plot. I read the data from files and append them. After I convert them into an array. It plots but does not take the theta_min and theta_mix correctly.As x value it takes only the position of the desired value but not the value itself.
Please suggest.

Thank you for you help.
[image: this is the output I get]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

Filename='DS_MNASP_12_RT-483K_'  
FileExtension= '.dat' 
FileNumberBegin =1 
FileNumberEnd =10 
theta_min=1
theta_max=10
RT = 290 
HT=523 


Filenames = []
    for i  in range(FileNumberBegin,FileNumberEnd + 1):
    Filenames.append(Filename + (4-len(str(i)))*'0' + str(i) + 'p' + 
                 FileExtension)

data=[]
for j in Filenames:
    data.append(np.genfromtxt(j, dtype='float', skip_header=41)) 
d=np.array(data)

ylabel = '$Temperature\/(k)$'
xlabel = '$2\/theta (degrees)$'



x = d[0,theta_min:theta_max,0] 
y = (np.arange(RT,HT+1, dtype='float64'))
z = d[:,theta_min:theta_max,1] 

X,Y = plt.meshgrid(x, y) 
Z = z 


xmin = theta_min
xmax = theta_max


im = plt.imshow(Z, origin='lower', aspect='auto', extent=[xmin, xmax, y[0], 
    y[-1]]) 

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_autoscale_on(False)
ax.set_xlabel(xlabel, fontsize = 30)
ax.set_ylabel(ylabel, fontsize = 30)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=20, pad =7, direction='out', width=2, top='off', 
right='off')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The output looks correct. x goes from theta_min to theta_max. What would you like to see instead?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But the issue is.. although X axis shows the correct theta value but in the plot I do not get the corresponding intensity value with respect to theta. the values plotted in the graph is the value for the 1st to 10th position of the array. I hope I am clear about my doubts

Comment: Fo example if I use extent xtent=(x[200], x[-1],y[0], y[-1])

Comment: That is unfortunately not clear. The image along the x axis show **all** values as expected.

Comment: Fo example if I use extent
     extent=(x[0], x[-1],y[0], y[-1]) it give the correct plotting with full theta range. I get this image
https://imgur.com/Es9Or15
But if I want to restrict the theta range then the problem occurs.
for example, if I put extent=(x[500], x[-1],y[0], y[-1])  then the plotting just shifts instead of giving me the exact range. I get the following image
https://imgur.com/GCOlBaS
I hope this helps
Thank you

Comment: You're possibly mixing up `extent` and `xlim`. So the extent is always the full range of the array. If you want to limit this range you would also need to slice the array differently.

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs.Now I understand and solved the problem by adding an extra line since I want to limit the view of the graph. 
plt.xlim(6, 20) after the imshow line
Thank you very much. Have a nice day